# can I freeze jalapeno peppers then use them for pepper jelly when my green peppers comne in?

Tags: jalapeno

My jalapeno peppers plants are loaded, but my green peppers aren't ready to pick yet. Can I freeze the jalapeno peppers  then thaw them out to make pepper jelly?

Comment: How do you usually prep your peppers when making your jelly? Are they roasted or just cooked?

Comment: http://jalapenomadness.com/preserve_jalapenos.html#.V2egL7iLTIU

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Just take the peppers out of the freezer and thaw and drain. Then use them as usual in your jelly or pepper mustard...whatever recipe you want. I freeze mine all the time.As a matter of fact, doing so now.